# How can we show that $3\gamma=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(xe^{1\over x}-e^{-{1\over x}}\Gamma\left({1\over x}\right)\right)?$

Tags: limits, euler-mascheroni-constant

**How can we show that**

$$3\gamma=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(xe^{1\over x}-e^{-{1\over x}}\Gamma\left({1\over x}\right)\right)?\tag1$$

Where $\gamma=0.577...$ is [Euler-Masheronic Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant)

It is all known that

$$\gamma=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(x-\Gamma\left(1\over x\right)\right)\tag2$$

Comment: $\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \left(xe^{a/x}- \Gamma(1/x)e^{-a/x}\right) = 2a+\gamma \,$ for $\,a\in\mathbb{R}$ --- special case:  $\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \left(xe^{\gamma/x}- \Gamma(1/x)e^{-\gamma/x}\right) = 3\gamma$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $x=1/t$ to get

$$L=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac1te^t-\Gamma(t)e^{-t}$$

Now note that

$$\Gamma(t)=\frac{\Gamma(t+1)}t$$

Thus,

\begin{align}L&=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{e^t-1}t-\frac{\Gamma(t+1)e^{-t}-1}t\\&=1-\frac d{dt}\Gamma(t+1)e^{-t}\bigg|_{t=0}\\&=2-\Gamma'(1)\\&=2+\gamma\end{align}

Which is the correct limit (you can check it numerically)

Comment: Short and clear, very nice .(+1) :-)